# How to secure Accouts.createUser() with Collection2 (server-side)

Tags: security, meteor, accounts

I'm new to Meteor and I have a little question about Collection2 and Accounts.

Currently, a user can create an account. This is handled by a Template event (client-side) which calls a Meteor method. This method is defined client-side and server-side.

Client-side, I do some UI stuff (nothing important) while server-side I'm creating the account.

Here is my server-side Meteor method :

```
Meteor.methods({

    'registerUser': function (user) {
        Accounts.createUser(user);
    }

});
```

I also use Collection2 package to check data before inserting or updating document :

```
Schema = {};

Schema.UserProfile = new SimpleSchema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        optional: false,
        label: "Name"
    }
});

Schema.User = new SimpleSchema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        optional: true,
        label: "Username"
    },
    emails: {
        type: Array,
        optional: true
    },
    "emails.$": {
        type: Object
    },
    "emails.$.address": {
        type: String,
        regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email,
        label: "Email address"
    },
    "emails.$.verified": {
        type: Boolean
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date
    },
    profile: {
        type: Schema.UserProfile,
        optional: true
    },
    services: {
        type: Object,
        optional: true,
        blackbox: true
    }
});

Meteor.users.attachSchema(Schema.User);
```

Okay so here I am. My problem is about getting potential errors returned by Collection2 while creating the user (server-side). Something like this :

```
Meteor.methods({

    'registerUser': function (user) {
        Accounts.createUser(user, (err, res) => {
            if(err) return err;
        });
        return true;
    }

});
```

But Meteor does not support yet callback for Accounts.createUser(). So even if I use Collection2, my user can submit bad inputs.

The question is : Is it possible to use Collection2 with Accounts in this case and how ?

Thanks for everything ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call [Accounts.createUser](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_createuser) you do not pass it an object with the schema as those found in the Meteor.users Collection.  You pass an options object with the specified fields:

> **Options**
>   **username** String
>   A unique name for this user.
>
> **email** String
>   The user's email address.
>
> **password** String
>   The user's password. This is not sent in plain text over the wire.
>
> **profile** Object
>   The user's profile, typically including the name field.

Called from the client this method does have a callback:

> **callback** Function
>   Client only, optional callback. Called with no arguments on success, or with a single Error argument on failure.

Don't create a Schema for the User object.

You could use your Schema.UserProfile to validate what is passed in the profile parameter though, and the best place to do this would be inside a [accountsServer.validateNewUser](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/accounts_validatenewuser) callback on the server.

```
Accounts.validateNewUser(function (user) {
  if(Match.test(user.profile, Schema.UserProfile))
    return true;
  throw new Meteor.Error(403, "Invalid UserProfile");
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a lot for your help.